# Consulta a varias tablas Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en MYSQL, en donde busco la totalidad de estudiantes de cada tabla de un semestre en particular.

Si el estudiante esta varias veces ingresado dentro de una tabla, solo me traerá el registro con la menor fecha de ingreso.

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero si el estudiante esta ingresado en cada tabla lo tendré 2 veces y lo que necesito es solo saber si estuvo en un semestre y no tener un estudiante 2 veces.

Espero que alguien me pueda indicar como hago la consulta para que de ambas tablas consultadas muestre solo 1 estudiante con la menor fecha de ingreso.

```
SELECT 
  a.rut, 
  a.nombres, 
  a.apellidos, 
  DATE_FORMAT(MIN(a.fecha_ingreso), '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_ingreso,

FROM form1 a INNER JOIN servicio s on s.id_form_1 = a.id_form_1
WHERE a.semestre_ano = $semestre and a.estatus = 1 GROUP BY 1,2,3

UNION

SELECT 
  b.rut, 
  b.nombres, 
  b.apellidos, 
  DATE_FORMAT(MIN(b.fecha_ingreso), '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_ingreso,

FROM form2 b INNER JOIN departamento dep on dep.id_form_2 = b.id_form_2 
WHERE b.semestre_ano = $semestre and b.estatus = 1 GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más rápida sería con subquerys:

```sql
select x.rut,
       x.nombres,
       x.apellidos,
       min(x.fecha_ingreso) as fecha_ingreso
from ( 
   SELECT 
     a.rut, 
     a.nombres, 
     a.apellidos, 
     DATE_FORMAT(MIN(a.fecha_ingreso), '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_ingreso,

   FROM form1 a INNER JOIN servicio s on s.id_form_1 = a.id_form_1
   WHERE a.semestre_ano = $semestre and a.estatus = 1 GROUP BY 1,2,3

   UNION

   SELECT 
     b.rut, 
     b.nombres, 
     b.apellidos, 
     DATE_FORMAT(MIN(b.fecha_ingreso), '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_ingreso,

   FROM form2 b 
       INNER JOIN departamento dep on dep.id_form_2 = b.id_form_2 
   WHERE b.semestre_ano = $semestre and b.estatus = 1 GROUP BY 1,2,3
) x
group by x.rut, x.nombres, x.apellidos
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, haré la consulta y te comento como me va

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias.